# SQL: Using a variable within a text field

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new at this so please bear with me. I've created the following stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE REMARK()
BEGIN
  #declare variable
  DECLARE v_newid, v_oldid VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

  #declare cursor
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT new, old
  FROM mydb.`tbl_id`;    

  #declare handle 
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  #open cursor
  OPEN cur1;

  #starts the loop
  the_loop: LOOP

    #get the values of each column into our variables
    FETCH cur1 INTO v_newid, v_oldid;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

    #Insert it
    INSERT INTO cherrycasino.`tbl_remarks` (player_id, user_tool_id, text)
    VALUES (v_newid, '103', 'User Copied from ES id:v_oldid');    

  END LOOP the_loop;

  CLOSE cur1;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

It is working as it should except for one thing. I want to insert some text in tbl_remarks using a variable I got from the cursor.

```
VALUES (v_newid, '103', 'User Copied from ES id:v_oldid');
```

I cannot transform back the variable v_oldid back. Am I missing some escape sequence here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was a simple concat of the string I want to use plus the variable.

```
VALUES (v_newid, '103', CONCAT('User Copied from ES id:', v_oldid));
```